# Rest template delete method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, restful-url

I'm trying to delete user by passing his id to Rest service.

Service controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws JsonProcessingException {
    User user = this.userService.getUserById(id);
    System.out.println(id);
    if (this.userService.getUserById(user.getId()) != null) {
        this.userService.deleteUser(user.getId());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);   
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(error("Sorry, an error occured!"), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

User service controller:

```
@RequestMapping("user/delete/{id}")
public String delete(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model){
    String uri = new String("http://localhost:8050/MavenSpringSafeHouse/remove/" + id);

     java.util.Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("id", "2");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.delete ( uri,  params );
    return "redirect:/users";
}
```

Error:

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Comment: Can you please try debugging the ServiceController. Your code is also throwing 404 in case a user is not found. Aside to that, inside your service controller client code you are appending the user Id directly to URL and also adding the same as parameter. You should instead use path param placeholder {id}. However, it won't cause any issue.

Comment: Which REST url you are hitting ? user/delete/{id} ? or /remove/{id} ? I am not clear on when are you getting the error ?

Comment: REST url -http://localhost:8050/MavenSpringSafeHouse/remove/" + id.
user/delete/{id} is my url to triger this controller.